# Saving SharedPreferences in Android Service

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences, android-service

I have a service for playing music in my application. I am trying to save a Boolean value for if the music is stopped or not for the user when he exits the app. When the music is playing and he quits the app using the "Exit" Button it should save the value, but when he re-enters the saved value is always "false".

The activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Boolean isMusicPlaying;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View exitButton=findViewById(R.id.exit);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    isMusicPlaying=getSharedPreferences("SFX", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("music", true);
    if(isMusicPlaying)
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){


    case R.id.exit: 
    {
        isMusicPlaying=getSharedPreferences("SFX", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("music", true);
        stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
        getSharedPreferences("SFX", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("music", isMusicPlaying).commit();
        if(isMusicPlaying)
            Toast.makeText(this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.finish();
    }
    }
}
```

}

The Service for the music:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

MediaPlayer player;
public static int lastStopped;

public static int getLastStopped() {
    return lastStopped;
}

public static void setLastStopped(int lastStopped) {
    MyService.lastStopped = lastStopped;
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.background);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(100,100);
    player.seekTo(getLastStopped());

}
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    getSharedPreferences("SFX", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("music", true).commit();
    player.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    getSharedPreferences("SFX", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("music", false).commit();
    setLastStopped(player.getCurrentPosition());
    player.pause();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you do write "false" to the SharedPreference when the Service is destroyed which will happen when you exit the application.

You may want to code the service as an foreground service. Please see [Googles developer reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Comment: If you notice the "exit" case in the activity, I stop the service and then put the value in the SharedPreference that was before the destroy.

Comment: The stopService(Intent) is a asynchronous call. The Service onDestroy() will overwrite previously written values.

Comment: I don't understand. I save the last value before the destruction in isMusicPlaying. When I destroy the service it overwrites it?

Comment: By the way, I before the this.finish() command I made a toast printing the value of isMusicPlaying. when the music is playing and I exit the app it prints "true"

Comment: Asynchronous calls enables processing to continue without waiting for the function to return a value. If you put logs in MyService.onDestroy() and prior to the this.finish() you will see that the MyService.onDestroy() is in fact called after this.finish()

Answer (score 1):

Better you should maintain a static boolean field in service and check it whether music is playing or not.That will be simple and code flow will be easy to understand.Why to make things complicated by using shared preference several time

```
  public class MyService extends Service {
  Public static boolean isMusicPlaying=false;
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   isMusicPlaying=true;
  .......
   }
```

In Activity just check

```
  if(MyService .isMusicPlaying)
        Toast.makeText(this, "YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 else
  startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
```